# How does Bourbon change the font size when you change your browser size?

Tags: css, fonts, sass, bourbon, neat

I am using Thoughtbot's Bitters/Neat/Bourbon stack. When I resize the browser window, the font size is changed to match the available space. However, when I change the contents of the screen via JS, the font size is not updated. How can I update the font size without having to resize the browser?

Comment: how do you exactly change the contents of the screen via JS(provide some code)?

Comment: Your question seems to be a very generic CSS/JS question. Bourbon and its libraries do not change the font size. You might want to do a bit of reading about how media queries work and what is the role of Javascript in a Web page. That will give you a better understanding of how these relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks guys - I couldn't figure out why Bourbon would be changing the size, and in the end, it was something else.

Answer (score 0):

By default Bitters doesn't change the font size when you change the browser size. See the typography file here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/_typography.scss

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot about the font size manipulation of [fullscreen.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) - that is what was changing my font-size property on page reload. Since this library does not expose the method that changes the font-size, I had to copy the method and call it when I change the contents of my window.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta set the font size for each @include...